# Analytic region of the function $z^{2 \alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

This is a paragraph from Ahlfors Complex Analysis

It states that for the function $z^{2 \alpha}$ where $0<\alpha<1$, it is possible to choose an analytical branch of the function whose argument lies between $-\pi \alpha$ and $3\pi \alpha$; that it is well defined and analytical within the region obtained by ommiting the negative imaginary axis.

My question is why can't a single valued analytical branch be defined on the negative imaginary axis? I suspect that it may have something to do with the possibility of defining a single valued analytical branch of $\ln z$ everywhere except on the non-positive real axis.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the negative imaginary axis, we could have also chosen a branch of $z^{2 \alpha}$ which is analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [0, e^{-\pi i/4} \infty)$. But, unless $\alpha = 1/2$, there doesn't exist a branch which is analytic on $\mathbb C$ or on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, $z = 0$ is a branch point.